# export sqldata into excel from Pivot table store procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, pivot

My Problem:
my store procedure have dynamic column. so i cannot insert into tabe.
so i need to export directly to excel. Below is my code. Below code is working fine.
i need either export excel directly from store procedure or how can i create dynamic table with store procedure
Pls help me.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PIVOT_Seats]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE 
@cols NVARCHAR(MAX),
@stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ', ', '') + '[' + T.showdateformat + ']' FROM 
(SELECT  DISTINCT showdateformat FROM vw_Pivot_Seat_ALL) AS T

SELECT @stmt = ' SELECT * FROM vw_Pivot_Seat_ALL AS T
    pivot (SUM(T.Qty)  FOR T.showdateformat IN (' + @cols + ')) AS P'
END
EXEC sp_executesql @STMT=@STMT
```

Pls help me

Maideen

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010+, go to the Data tab, add a connection to your SQL database, when you get to the 'Select Table' dialog, just choose any valid table (we can change it later).  Then next dialog will be called 'Import Table.'  From here follow the directions on [this page](http://bisherryli.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/excel-pivottable-%E2%80%93-from-a-stored-procedure/), viz. click on Properties and then the 'Definition' tab.  Change the Command Type to something other than 'Table' and Command Text to EXEC usp_PIVOT_Seats and you should be good to go.